# The display contents of v-text-field are not updated immediately

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

The display contents of v-text-field is not updated immediately.

How to reproduce:

1. Go [Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)
2. Input more than 10 characters in the text-field.
3. Deleted longer than 10 characters in the text-fields, but not immediately.It will not be deleted during input. It is deleted when focus is removed.

I am using v-text-field in a custom component:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field clearable
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-model="data"
    >
  </v-text-field>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
  import {ref, computed } from "vue";
  import {} from "vue"

  const props = defineProps<{modelValue:string}>();
  const emits = defineEmits<{
    (e:"update:modelValue", text:string): void;
  }>();

const data = computed({
    get(){
        return props.modelValue;
    },
    set(value:string){
        console.log(value)
        emits("update:modelValue", convert(value))
    }
})

// Delete over 10 chars
const convert = (target:string) =>{
    if(target.length > 10){
        return target.substring(0,10)
    }
    return target;
}
</script>
```

The parent component uses the custom component as follows:

```
<template>
  ...
      <custom-text-field v-model="text"></custom-text-field>
  ...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  ...
  const text = ref("");
  ...
</script>
```

It will be deleted during input.

Comment: If you are trying to limit the input to max 10 chars - use the `maxlength="10"` native attribute.

Comment: You need to have a vuetify playgrond (or similar) that we can use to see the problem. It takes too long for us to download and install your project - which may be dangerous anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I create Vuetify Playground.